# RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout. Show only complety visible items on a screen

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need to create a horizontal list of items that only displays fully visible items.
[image]

But as you can see, my recycler view show a particular element. I use a horizontal LinearLayoutManager.

I add 10 elements, but recycler view has room only for 3. I need to show only 3, but it always show me 3 and particular element.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My item layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAnimalName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ASDAS"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter and activity are plain.

How can I show only visible 3 items?

Edit.
I must to disable scroll. So i am using:

```
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false) {
            @Override
            public boolean canScrollHorizontally() {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

Edit 2. These methods show -1 always:

```
int findLastVisibleItemPosition();
int findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
```

Comment: Let me clarify: You would like to show all fully visible items and hide everything else, and not allow to scroll. So all items, which are hidden will never be shown. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: In fact, I would say, that if there are more items than can be shown, the last item will always be partly visible. I mean, even if 4 items totally fits the size of the recycler view, the fifth will be created but will be totally hidden out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class HideLastDecorator() : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {

override fun onDraw(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
    super.onDraw(c, parent, state)
    val count = parent.childCount
    for (i in 0 until count) {
        parent.getChildAt(i).visibility = if (count == i - 1) View.INVISIBLE else View.VISIBLE 
    }
}
}
```

and add it to your recyclerView Decorations

```
appsRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(HideLastDecorator())
```

Sorry for Kotlin :)

`View.INVISIBLE` is important, because if the View becomes GONE, it will be removed from the measuring of the RecyclerView's content and the new ViewHolder would be added.

I prefer to work careful with `OnClickListener` if any is set for the ViewHolder's content.

Comment: Btw if the View.Visibility State is not changed by this method, this will not request any redrawing.

Comment: count == i is always false

Answer (score 1):

Below code will work for you. A little explanation: Extend `RecyclerView` and override `onLayout()` method. Once `RecyclerView` is ready iterate through all visible (on-screen) children of `RecyclerView` and apply your logic. In our case we'll draw `BounddingBox` for every `nth` child and `RecyclerView`. If child's bounds lie inside `RecyclerView`'s bounds then show that child otherwise set visibility to `GONE`/`INVISIBLE`.

```
public class CustomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    Rect recyclerViewBounds = new Rect();
    Rect currentChildViewBounds = new Rect();

    public CustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRecyclerView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        recyclerViewBounds.set(l, t, r, b);

        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View currentChild = getChildAt(i);

            currentChildViewBounds.set(currentChild.getLeft(), currentChild.getTop(), currentChild.getRight(), currentChild.getBottom());
            currentChild.setVisibility(recyclerViewBounds.contains(currentChildViewBounds) ? VISIBLE : GONE);  // or INVISBLE instead of GONE
        }
    }
}
```

**And most importantly:** In your `xml` file use `com.your.packagename.CustomRecyclerView` instead of  `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`.

**NOTE:** Please refrain from any object initialization inside `onLayout()`. What I mean is don't move the object initializations inside `onLayout()` to make it "fancier".

Answer (score 1):

None of the proposed answer worked as expected, so there ItemDecoration that i made, it checks if view completely visible in layout manager, and hide rest of views

```
class HideNotFullyVisibleDecorator : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
    override fun onDraw(c: Canvas, parent: RecyclerView, state: RecyclerView.State) {
        super.onDraw(c, parent, state)
        
        val count = parent.childCount
        for (i in 0 until count) {
            val currentChild = parent.getChildAt(i)

            currentChild.visibility =
                if (parent.layoutManager?.isViewPartiallyVisible(currentChild, true, false) == true) 
                    View.VISIBLE 
                else 
                    View.GONE

        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `recycler.addItemDecoration(HideNotFullyVisibleDecorator())`

Also in my case I disabled scrolling for recycler

Answer (score 0):

Recycler view is a Scrollable container which holds viewholders and recycles on scroll-up and down,
So it will display as much data as possible on screen, and that fourth half-visible item that you've shown in screenshot is just default behaviour of every scrollable view in android.

You have to customize your viewholders to adjust accordingly on runtime so that only fully visible items should be rendered.

You can do something like:

```
val availableWidth = screenWidth - (textViewWidth)
val itemWidth = (availableWidth / 3)
```

Comment: All items in rv has own size, and after recyclerView i have another view. I can not use screen width as entry point to count sizes.